# jailbreak iphone reinstall app but the notification BadgeNumber still exists

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, jailbreak, reinstall

There is app which installed on a jailbreak iphones. And we've also implemented the APNs feature. So the problem is :

1. the app got five notifications and the BadgeNumber shows on the icon is five.
2. then I uninstall the app, and reinstall it.
3. when the reintsall was done, the BadgeNumber on the icon **still shows five**.

====>I think when the reinstall was done ,the BadgeNumber should be **Zero**. Is it right?

Comment: Is this a normal App Store app, that happens to be installed on jailbroken phones (signed with a valid Apple provisioning profile)?  Or a true **jailbreak app**, that's not codesigned with Apple provisioning profiles, and installed in /Applications?

Comment: It's a true **JailBreak App**. and installed in the /User/Application folder through third party tools.

Comment: Which 3rd-party tool?  I guess I'm wondering how you code signed your app.  What I call a true jailbreak app is either signed by a self-signed certificate (not an Apple one), or fake code signed with `ldid`.  Is that what you have, or have you signed with a normal Apple Ad Hoc provisioning profile?

Comment: the tool is 91 assistant, and I use the below code to do this:<br/> NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`<br/>
 `if(![defaults objectForKey:"firstRun"]){`
        //first lanuch on this device
        `self.firstRun = TRUE;`
        `[defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:"firstRun"];`
`}else {`
        `//had once launched on this device before`
        `self.firstRun = FALSE;`
}`
 `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Comment: Thanks, Alex, but you still haven't said how you are code signing your app.